# Flutter app doesn't show the map view in the app

Tags: google-maps, flutter

Currently I'm learning flutter and I wanted to integrate google map with my flutter app. So I did everything as flutter blog says. Here is my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;

  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  void _onMapTypeButtonPressed() {
    if (_currentMapType == MapType.normal) {
      mapController.updateMapOptions(
        GoogleMapOptions(mapType: MapType.satellite),
      );
      _currentMapType = MapType.satellite;
    } else {
      mapController.updateMapOptions(
        GoogleMapOptions(mapType: MapType.normal),
      );
      _currentMapType = MapType.normal;
    }
  }

  void _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
    mapController.addMarker(
      MarkerOptions(
        position: LatLng(
          mapController.cameraPosition.target.latitude,
          mapController.cameraPosition.target.longitude,
        ),
        infoWindowText: InfoWindowText('Random Place', '5 Star Rating'),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              options: GoogleMapOptions(
                trackCameraPosition: true,
                cameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: _center,
                  zoom: 11.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: _onMapTypeButtonPressed,
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.map, size: 36.0),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: _onAddMarkerButtonPressed,
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.padded,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add_location, size: 36.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my android manifest file,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="neuroonnetworks.com.flutterapp">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flutter_app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.<my google map api key>"
            android:value="<my google map api key>"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

And I update the dependencies to pubspec.yaml with `google_maps_flutter: ^0.0.3+3`

So my problem is, there are no any errors in console and my mobile gives the view like following.

[image]
So what went wrong? Did I miss something? Why is it not showing the google map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide API Key in yuor Manifest
Guide for Android:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup

Comment: I provided it. For security issues I didn't include it in the question